# Facebook Graph API throws "User is not admin or developer of this application" exception Error #272

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are building a Facebook app to feed custom audiences from our system. Our clients will login via Facebook and with the token we got we need to manage their ad accounts to upload custom audiences.

We followed these steps:

1. created a Facebook app.
2. added Facebook login to our web app with this scope:
       'ads_management,manage_pages,business_management'.
3. collected token from an user who is not the administrator of our
       Facebook app.
4. via Graph API fetched the ad accounts list of the user.
5. called v2.12/act_{0}/customaudiences?access_token={1}&fields=description.

When we try to reach custom audiences Graph API returns the JSON below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#272) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the application. User is not admin or developer of this application.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 272,
        "fbtrace_id": "B+lKfUAU320"
    }
 }
```

What we are doing wrong? Why API returns this exception?
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely a matter of access level - which one are you on? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Comment: We are on development access level. But we are trying to apply Basic access level. Could this be the problem?